# Rendering Problems: Failed to load platform rendering library (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, rendering, platform

I've tried every solution I've found, including but not limited to changing the API, I have added **JDK_HOME**, and changing the theme.

One thing to keep in mind that this is my very first app in Android Studio. (I switched to Eclipse after I couldn't figure it out and created a HelloWorld app with a button, but then I heard that Android development wouldn't be supported by Eclipse anymore and figured I should start with Android Studio.)

If you could provide your answers in the simplest way, I would be forever grateful.

Comment: Did you tried to rebuild and sync the gradle ?

Comment: I did now! It didn't work though :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just have to select a different Android version for the preview. 
In my case I've removed some preview SDK versions and the preview failed to work. It seems the preview was not updated too.

You find the option in the upper right corner of the preview window.

I found a short YouTube Video showing it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49CF6uU38Wo

Answer (score 0):

> "Rendering Problems: Failed to load platform rendering library
>   (Android Studio)"

What i have done in my situation, i have downloaded the latest version of "Android SDK Build Tool" and my problem is solved. I believe that will solve your problem too. Well as our other friends refer to change the version of "Android API Target (Like; 24,23 and so on)" that will also solve your problem but not the exact solution, that's my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Change Android version to 23, It worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!! Try to avoid comment in answer section unless you have specific answer. Please use comment box below and Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. :)